# Upload image to website using multipart/form-data idhttp delphi

Tags: delphi, indy

I need help in solving the problem of uploading a photo to wildberries.ru using IdHTTP. Post data looks like this when loading an image from the site:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCpJAFY6AlIHK7dZt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nmId"

13927988
------WebKitFormBoundaryCpJAFY6AlIHK7dZt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"; filename="13927988-2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

{here these photos are most likely}
------WebKitFormBoundaryCpJAFY6AlIHK7dZt--
```

can't figure out how to transfer data via IdHTTP. I am using RAD Studio 10.3.1 Rio, Indy 10.

Comment: Please edit your question. Your last sentence is confusing. "Loading" means "upload" or "Download"? Is "upload" then "...to the site". Also add the code you use and the error messages you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` has an overloaded `Post()` method that takes a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` as input, which in turn has `AddFormField()` and `AddFile()` methods. For example:

```pascal
uses
  ..., IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdMultipartFormData;

var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
    SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;

    Data := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      with Data.AddFormField(‘nmId’, ‘13927988’) do
      begin
        ContentType := '';
        ContentTransfer := '';
      end;
      with Data.AddFile(‘photos’, ‘full path to\13927988-2.jpg’, ‘image/jpeg’) do
        ContentTransfer := '';
      HTTP.Post(‘https://www.wildberries.ru/...’, Data);
    finally
      Data.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remy. I changed your code a bit. I tried to send a request, but in response I received an error from the 400 Bad Request server. There is speculation that the case is in Boundary. My request looks like this:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name = "nmId"
Content-Type: text / plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

13927987
---------- 092520110009823
Content-Disposition: form-data; name = "photos"; filename = "3.jpg"
Content-Type: image / jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`
How to generate a boundary similar to WebKitFormBoundaryefyWRVXQv7B4XPBt?

Comment: And how to remove the following lines: `Content-Type: text / plain request
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`, `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`?

Comment: @Yaroslav "*How to generate a boundary similar to ...*" - the `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Boundary` property is read-only, but its `FBoundary` field is `protected`, so you can modify it directly via an accessor class, eg `type TIdMultipartFormDataStreamAccess = class(TIdMultipartFormDataStream) end; TIdMultipartFormDataStreamAccess(Data).FBoundary := ...;`. Though, the actual boundary value should not matter as long as it is unique, which `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`'s default boundaries are. The actual boundary value is sent in the request's `Content-Type` so the server knows what to look for

Comment: @Yaroslav "*how to remove the following lines*" - the `Add...` methods return a pointer to a `TIdFormDataField` object, which has `ContentType` and `ContentTransfer` properties you can blank out. I have updated my answer to show this.